# How to move an element to just below a fixed header

Tags: javascript, viewport, offset, scrolltop

I am trying to move each `<li>` to top of the screen on `onClick()`, and its working using `scrollIntoView();` but because my header is fixed small part of the `<li>` goes below the header. How can I scroll the `<li>` to just below the header.

**HTML**

```
    <header></header>
<div id="wrapper">
   <ul>
       <li id='li1' onClick="moveup(1)"> blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
       </li>
         <li id='li2' onClick='moveUp(2)'> blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
       </li>
       <li id='li3' onClick='moveUp(3)'> blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
       </li>
        <li id='li4' onClick='moveUp(4)'> blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
       </li>
        <li id='li1' onClick='moveUp(1)'> blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
       </li>
       <li id='li5' onClick='moveUp(5)'> blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
       </li>
       </ul>   
</div> <!--end wrapper-->
```

**css**

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#col1 {
 background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {                    
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    display: block;
}

li {
     display: block;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;  
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function moveup(x){
   document.getElementById('li'+x).scrollIntoView();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jn74M/2/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `scrollIntoView()`, push it down by 50px, using something like this:

```
scrollBy(0, -50);
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with other units? (`rem`, `pt`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

instead of `onClick` use `onclick`. also you defined function as `moveup` but calling `moveUp`.

With jQuery it would be easy to achieve the functionality you need. check this http://jsfiddle.net/alekperos/Jn74M/3/

HTML

```
<header></header>

  <div id="wrapper">
     <ul>
         <li id='li1'> blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
             blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
             blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
             blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
             blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
         </li>
           <li id='li2'> blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
             blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
             blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
             blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
             blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
         </li>
         <li id='li3'> blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
             blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
             blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
             blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
             blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
         </li>
          <li id='li4'> blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
             blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
             blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
             blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
             blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
         </li>
         <li id='li5'> blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
             blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
             blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
             blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
             blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
         </li>
         </ul>   
  </div> <!--end wrapper-->
```

JS

```
// on click of list element
$('li').click(function(){
   // scroll the window in the amount of position of current clicked list element
   // minus 
   // the amount that corresponds to the height of the header
   $(window).scrollTop($(this).position().top - $('header').height())
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your example so it works: [jsfiddle.net/t3go7b0u/4][1] I know this question is old and you might have solved it already... But for the record. Changes: position:sticky on header and fixed/sticky elements scroll plugin [smartScroll][2]

Changes:

```
   header {
      position: fixed;
   }

   $('#li' + x).smartScroll("start");
```

```js
function moveUp(x){
   // document.getElementById('li'+x).scrollIntoView();
   // https://github.com/webdevelopers-eu/DNA-Smart-Scroll
   $('#li' + x).smartScroll("start");
}
```

```css
header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}

*[onclick] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
*[onclick]:hover {
  outline: 2px solid orange;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#col1 {
 background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {                    
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    display: block;
}

li {
     display: block;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;  
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/webdevelopers-eu/DNA-Smart-Scroll/main/jquery.smartscroll.js"></script>

<header></header>
<div id="wrapper">
   <ul>
       <li id='li1' onClick="moveUp(1)"> blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
       </li>
         <li id='li2' onClick='moveUp(2)'> blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
       </li>
       <li id='li3' onClick='moveUp(3)'> blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
       </li>
        <li id='li4' onClick='moveUp(4)'> blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
       </li>
        <li id='li1' onClick='moveUp(1)'> blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
       </li>
       <li id='li5' onClick='moveUp(5)'> blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
           blah blah blah blah blah <br/>
       </li>
       </ul>   
</div> <!--end wrapper-->
```

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/t3go7b0u/4
  [2]: https://github.com/webdevelopers-eu/DNA-Smart-Scroll
```